# Swing and JavaFX native image with GraalVM - no awt in java.library.path error

Tags: swing, javafx, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I am trying to create a `native-image` of a straightforward application using `gluonfx-maven-plugin` but it requires being a Swing application with `JFrame` and `JFXPanel` to run JavaFX UI as I am using Java Chromium Embedded Framework (JCEF) to replace Javafx WebView on Windows as GraalVM does not currently support it. And JavaFX does not render the browser correctly, hence Swing usage.
Plugin's `build` command runs perfectly fine but when I try to run the image using `nativerun` it fails to run.

```
C:\Users\Yash\Documents\Gluon-SingleViewProject\target\gluonfx>mvn -f "C:\Users\Yash\Documents\Gluon-SingleViewProject\pom.xml" com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:nativerun
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------< com.gluonapplication:gluon-singleviewproject >------------
[INFO] Building Gluon-SingleViewProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.15:nativerun (default-cli) @ gluon-singleviewproject ---
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] ==================== RUN TASK ====================
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awt in java.library.path
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibraryRelative(NativeLibrarySupport.java:132)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:47)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1388)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1386)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:169)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1385)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1423)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1397)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:624)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:518)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:518)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:518)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:518)
[Tue Sep 13 20:37:44 IST 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:518)
             _______  ___      __   __  _______  __    _
            |       ||   |    |  | |  ||       ||  |  | |
            |    ___||   |    |  | |  ||   _   ||   |_| |
            |   | __ |   |    |  |_|  ||  | |  ||       |
            |   ||  ||   |___ |       ||  |_|  ||  _    |
            |   |_| ||       ||       ||       || | |   |
            |_______||_______||_______||_______||_|  |__|

    Access to the latest docs, tips and tricks and more info on
    how to get support? Register your usage of Gluon Substrate now at

    https://gluonhq.com/activate

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.139 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-13T20:37:46+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Application Code**

```
package com.gluonapplication;

import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import org.cef.CefApp;
import org.cef.CefClient;
import org.cef.CefSettings;
import org.cef.browser.CefBrowser;
import org.cef.browser.CefFrame;
import org.cef.handler.CefAppHandlerAdapter;
import org.cef.handler.CefDisplayHandlerAdapter;
import org.cef.handler.CefFocusHandlerAdapter;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.Serial;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5570653778104813836L;
    private final JTextField address_;
    private final CefApp cefApp_;
    private final CefClient client_;
    private final CefBrowser browser_;
    private final Component browerUI_;
    private boolean browserFocus_ = true;

    private MainFrame(String startURL, boolean useOSR, boolean isTransparent) {
        CefApp.addAppHandler(new CefAppHandlerAdapter(null) {
            @Override
            public void stateHasChanged(org.cef.CefApp.CefAppState state) {
                if (state == CefApp.CefAppState.TERMINATED) System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = useOSR;
        cefApp_ = CefApp.getInstance(settings);

        client_ = cefApp_.createClient();

        browser_ = client_.createBrowser(startURL, useOSR, isTransparent);
        browerUI_ = browser_.getUIComponent();

        address_ = new JTextField(startURL, 100);
        address_.addActionListener(e -> browser_.loadURL(address_.getText()));

        client_.addDisplayHandler(new CefDisplayHandlerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAddressChange(CefBrowser browser, CefFrame frame, String url) {
                address_.setText(url);
            }
        });

        address_.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (!browserFocus_) return;
                browserFocus_ = false;
                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().clearGlobalFocusOwner();
                address_.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        client_.addFocusHandler(new CefFocusHandlerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onGotFocus(CefBrowser browser) {
                if (browserFocus_) return;
                browserFocus_ = true;
                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().clearGlobalFocusOwner();
                browser.setFocus(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTakeFocus(CefBrowser browser, boolean next) {
                browserFocus_ = false;
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(address_, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(browerUI_, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        javafx.scene.control.Button button = new javafx.scene.control.Button("Print");
        button.setOnAction(e -> browser_.print());
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(button));
        getContentPane().add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                CefApp.getInstance().dispose();
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!CefApp.startup(args)) {
            System.out.println("Startup initialization failed!");
            return;
        }

        boolean useOsr = false;
        new MainFrame("https://www.google.com", useOsr, false);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gluonapplication</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluon-singleviewproject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Gluon-SingleViewProject</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>18.0.2</javafx.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.15</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.gluonapplication.MainFrame</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.friwi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcefmaven</artifactId>
            <version>105.3.36</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>me.friwi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.friwi</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluegen-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.friwi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>host</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: GraalVM doen't have support for AWT/Swing outside of Linux. GluonFX plugin doesn't support JavaFX's WebView on Windows yet, so there is nothing much you could do... Ideally a pure JavaFX implementation of JCEF should do it... but of course that is quite a challenge.

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried pure JCEF version for JavaFX but it renders blurry web pages. Is it possible to use any other distribution of GraalVM which supports both i.e. AWT/Swing and JavaFX on Windows.

Comment: There is no such thing as another GraalVM distribution with AWT support for Windows. Best chances are a pure JCEF for JavaFX. Does it work fine with `gluonfx:run`?

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes the application with `JFrame` and `JFXPanel` runs just fine with `gluonfx:run`

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried BellSoft Liberica Native Image Kit, which supports AWT/Swing on windows see this [link](https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2022/08/05/liberica-native-image-kit-22-2-0-and-21-3-3-builds-are-out/), but the problem occurs when I try to mix those two things (Swing and JavaFX), then it doesn't work.

Comment: Didn’t know about that “kit”. I take it’s a GraalVM build with AWT support for Windows. However it doesn’t seem to include JavaFX support, and I’m unsure you can combine it with the GluonFX plugin.

Comment: It does support JavaFX see this [link](https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2022/08/24/turning-javafx-apps-into-native-images/) and even comes with a build that contains JavaFX modules as well with graalVM

Comment: I see, so you don’t longer need the GluonFX plugin?  Even if the native kit doesn’t have media/web, it could build a native image with JCEF?

Comment: @Yashgarg what is the error you get with NIK? Does it happen at compile time or run time?

Comment: @peterz @peterz it happens at compile time. `Fatal error: com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError$HostedError: class com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.newimpl.InteropFactoryN not found` This class doesn't even exists in that package of javafx swing dependency.

Comment: @JoséPereda May be it is able to use JCEF but I am not sure about it, as the executable doesn't run if copied to somewhere else.

Comment: @JoséPereda And please can you explain me why gluonfx plugin compiles it first to a shared library and then perform linking. And what exactly is going on when this `link` command is called on it.

Comment: The `InteropFactoryN` class does exist, I can see it in the `lib/modules` at least in NIK 22.1. Do you have `--add-modules javafx.swing` on your command line?

Comment: @peterz yes I have see this `path-to-jdk\bin\native-image.cmd --add-modules javafx.swing,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls -Djava.awt.headless=false -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=conf-dir\reflect-config.json -H:JNIConfigurationFiles=conf-dir\jni-config.json -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=conf-dir\resource-config.json -jar testingPurposeJavaFX.jar Application`

Comment: @peterz where is this `lib/modules` located in?

Comment: Should be `path-to-jdk\lib\modules`. Use `jimage list` to print its contents

Comment: @peterz on which platform are you looking ? Bcz I cannot see it in windows

Comment: Linux, NIK version openjdk11-22.1.0